# SSL test always return "This server supports TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1" nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

I did an SSL test in https://www.ssllabs.com and I got **B**

after that, I only enabled *ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;* and do nginx restart and reload and retest again but the same result appears. I have Firewall and WAF in front of my app.

Comment: *"I have Firewall and WAF in front of my app."* - a WAF can analyze the traffic only if it terminates the TLS connection. Thus check the settings in the WAF.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the TLS version and ciphers in the WAF configuration